# WEBRTC peer connection blocked in UAE where as webRTC call to and from other countries works

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I am using React Native WebRTC to develop p2p calling application. It works everywhere except UAE and maybe Middle East.

I am using my own TURN server with port 4211 also tried TURN server with port 443 as mentioned in this answer. But that never works when I call to UAE from other countries. On the other hand incoming calls from UAE to other countries works on few network.

Comment: That sounds expected. The UAE and other middle east countries control the ISPs and telecoms, and they block stuff like that.

Comment: any solution to make it work

Comment: Change the government policy.